# OpenMP parallel quicksort implementation (C)

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, sorting, openmp

I'm trying to implement parallel quicksort. My approach is to split partition work between multiple threads and then merge the results (also using multiple threads). Note that the same pivot is used for all threads during partitioning.

Algorithm yields correct results. Unfortunately, it works much slower than sequential version regeardless of amount of threads (tested on 2/4/8 threads, 5000000 elements).

After tests I'm still not able to track down the root cause of performance issue, so I'm asking for directions.

I would like to stick with this approach of parallization if possible. It is more understandable for me than recursion parallization that seems to be more popular.

Here is my code:

```
...

int parallelPartition(int* arr, int l, int r)
{
  // amount of elements that will be sorted
  int elements = (r - l + 1);

  // if too few elements - use sequential partitioning
  if(elements < THREADS)
    return partition(arr, l, r);

  // amount of elements per thread - last thread can use different number of elements
  int elementsPerThread = elements / THREADS;

  // split index calculated of results from all threads
  int masterSplitIdx = -1;

  // array helpers
  int leftLengths[THREADS] = {0};
  int offsetLeft[THREADS] = {0};
  int rightLengths[THREADS] = {0};
  int offsetRight[THREADS] = {0};
  int splitIdxs[THREADS] = {0};

  /////////////////////////////
  // PARALLEL PARTITION PHASE
  /////////////////////////////
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(THREADS)
  {
      // number of thread
      int n = omp_get_thread_num();

      // pivot - common for all threads
      int pivot = arr[l];

      // calculate range for thread - data that this thread will be working on
      int currentThreadL = l + elementsPerThread * n;
      int currentThreadR = n == THREADS-1 ? r : l + elementsPerThread * (n+1) - 1;

      // precise number of elements that will be used by thread
      int threadElements = (currentThreadR - currentThreadL + 1);

      // local copy - slice of the whole array that will be used by thread
      int* threadArray = (int *) malloc ( threadElements * sizeof(int) );
      memcpy(threadArray, arr + currentThreadL, threadElements * sizeof(int));

      int localSplitIdx = partitionByPivot(threadArray, pivot, 0, threadElements - 1);
      int splitIdx = localSplitIdx + currentThreadL;
      splitIdxs[n] = splitIdx;

      // copy back to original array
      memcpy(arr + currentThreadL, threadArray, threadElements * sizeof(int));

      // save information about partitioning (lengths of left and right side)
      // for later usage (merging)
      leftLengths[n] = (splitIdx - currentThreadL);
      rightLengths[n] = (currentThreadR - splitIdx + 1);

      free(threadArray);
  }

  // calculate offsets for each thread
  // they will be used for merging
  for(int i = 1; i < THREADS; ++i)
  {
    offsetLeft[i] = offsetLeft[i-1] + leftLengths[i-1];
    offsetRight[i] = offsetRight[i-1] + rightLengths[i-1];
  }

  // calculate split index that will be used for calculating
  // where to put right side and split index returned from function
  masterSplitIdx = offsetLeft[THREADS-1] + leftLengths[THREADS-1];

  /////////////////////////////
  // PARALLEL MERGE PHASE
  /////////////////////////////

  // temporary array for copying
  int* tmpArray = (int*) malloc(elements * sizeof(int));

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(THREADS)
  {
    // number of thread
    int n = omp_get_thread_num();

    // calculate range for thread - data that this thread will be working on
    int currentThreadL = l + elementsPerThread * n;
    int currentThreadR = n == THREADS-1 ? r : l + elementsPerThread * (n+1) - 1;

    // precise number of elements that will be used by thread
    int threadElements = (currentThreadR - currentThreadL + 1);

    // merge left parts
    memcpy(tmpArray + offsetLeft[n], arr + currentThreadL, (splitIdxs[n] - currentThreadL) * sizeof(int));

    // merge right parts
    memcpy(tmpArray + masterSplitIdx + offsetRight[n], arr + splitIdxs[n], (currentThreadR - splitIdxs[n] + 1) * sizeof(int));

    #pragma omp barrier

    // copy back to original array
        memcpy(arr + currentThreadL, tmpArray + elementsPerThread * n, threadElements * sizeof(int));
    }

    // cleanup
  free(tmpArray);

  return masterSplitIdx + l;
}

void quickSort(int* array, int l, int r)
{
   int splitIdx;

   if(l < r)
   {
        splitIdx = parallelPartition(array, l, r);
        quickSort(array, l, splitIdx - 1);
        quickSort(array, splitIdx + 1, r);
   }
}
...
```

`partitionByPivot` is a sequential function that does partitioning in similar way to `partition` function.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What's the ratio between parallel executions? Your parallel version does more work than a sequential one, and worse data locality can have a much larger effect than added parallelism. If 2/4/8 threads have the same run time, there's probably some serialization of execution. If you do get speedup, the overhead of parallelism is the problem.

Comment: @eran Results are as follows: 8 threads - ~ 6s, 4 threads - ~ 6s, 2 threads ~7s (all tests use 5*10^6 elements).

Comment: All those calls to mempy() are an issue. All threads should be operating on the same original array.

Comment: I had a version without memcpy() - operating on <code>arr</code> variable. It had similar performance.

Comment: How did you measure time? Please provide a [mcve] (and report your specific results for that specific code). What hardware do you run on? What are your compiler versions and options?

Comment: Also note that a normal quicksort implementation for 5M integers takes about 0.4 s on my machine, so your version seems very inefficient to begin with.

Comment: For recursive parallelism, OpenMP tasks are much more natural. You have huge oversubscription...